# UTF-8 characters saved as ? on Linux MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, utf-8

I have a Spring App with Tomcat and MySql who runs with no problems in Windows, but when it's running on Linux server, special utf-8 characters (like spanish Ñ) are saved in Mysql table with the ? symbol.
If I change this character directly on the database, it's correctly showed by the app. It's when I save the object using the app when the Ñ is replaced by the ?

Other apps are running on the same server and they don't have this issue.
The data base has the UTF-8 charset/collation.

Can anybody help?
Thanks a million!

Comment: Maybe read this [UTF-8 All The Way Through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) it may give you some clues

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `Datasource URL` includes **UTF-8 character encoding!**

**Example:**

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!! I couldn't set exactly that way because I have a XML file instead of a properties file, but that was the solution. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the right encoding in your **properties file** or in your **DataSource URL**. (**characterEncoding=UTF-8**)

Comment: Exactly, as I said to ismlyldz, that was the solution. Thank you very much!!!